# Template is ignored in Telerik Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, nopcommerce

I have the following grid inside an MVC application:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<PartnerModel.JustMyModel>()
                      .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(x => x.Id).RouteKey("id"))
                      .Name("assignedproducts-grid")
                      .Columns(columns =>
                      {
                          columns.Bound(x => x.IsAssigned)
                              .Template(
                                @<text><input type="checkbox" name="IsAssigned" id="chkIsAssigned" @(item.IsAssigned ? "checked" : "unchecked") />
                                </text>)
                              ;
                          columns.Bound(x => x.AssignedProductName);
                          columns.Command(commands => commands.Delete().Text(T("Admin.Common.Delete").Text))
                              .Title(T("Admin.Common.Delete").Text);
                      })
      .Pageable(settings => settings.PageSize(gridPageSize).Position(GridPagerPosition.Both))
      .DataBinding(binding => binding.Ajax()
```

While all Data is displayed, the value of the boolean Property "IsAssigned" is displayed as a string ("true" or "false") where instead it should display the checkbox (defined in ".Template()")

The grid looks exactly the same when I remove the Template() - Part. So it seems to completely be ignored. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Because the Databinding is Ajax I had to use .ClientTemplate() instead of .Template()